# icomoon svg fonts icons distorted when refreshing browser

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, glyphicons

I'm having an intermittent problem with browser not rendering the correct fonts to display icons.

I'm using icomoon.io to create a custom set of icons as a font, and I'm using the following Scss file -

```css
@import "icons-list";
$fonticon-prefix: 'air';
$font-family-fontello:  "fontello";
@mixin create-font-icon($position, $styles) {
    @if $position == both {
        $position: 'before, &:after';
    }
    // Either a :before or :after pseudo-element, or both, defaulting to :before
    &:#{$position} {

        @if $styles {
            // Supportive icon styles required
      display: inline-block;
            speak: none;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            font-family: '#{$font-family-fontello}';
        }
        // Include any extra rules supplied for the pseudo-element
        @content;
    }
}


[class^="#{$fonticon-prefix}-"],
[class*=" #{$fonticon-prefix}-"] {
    @include create-font-icon(before, true);
}

// Setup a class name for each icon
@each $fontIconInfo in $font-icons-list {
  $icon-name:nth($fontIconInfo, 1);
    $iconHexaCode:nth($fontIconInfo, 2);
    $icon-font-size:nth($fontIconInfo, 3);
    $icon-color:nth($fontIconInfo, 4);

    .#{$fonticon-prefix}-#{$icon-name}:before {
        content: $iconHexaCode;
    @if ($icon-font-size != '') {
      font-size: #{$icon-font-size};
    }
    @if ($icon-color != '') {
      color: #{$icon-color};
    }

    }
}

.air-more,.air-more:after,.air-more:before {
    width: 0.25em;
    height: 0.25em;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdjyk.jpg)

It Rendering in Browser like the below picture

This bug only happens rarely when rendering in the browser and is pretty hard to reproduce. please help me to find the problem.

Comment: we have the same issue, too. We seem to only have it when being in a virtual environment with citrix, where the workplace injects some JS from citrix. Is that by any chance for you like that aswell?